# Android: NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED crashing

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification

I am using persistent notification and for that, I need to use `IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED`, I can't use other importance as it is not giving extra padding at the bottom of the notification. Any Suggestions?

```
 NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED);
    chan.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: the same problem with me plz help :)